# How to implement Bing Search in a PHP Static site?

Tags: php, search, bing

Hi friends I want to implement Bing Search my for My Static Site So that it when I put somthing in the search bar it should search my hole site for the contents to match the search keywords.

Please Can any one help me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bing.com/siteowner

Here is Bing's "Getting Started" site, which should help you get started and guide you through setting this up on your website.

Comment: I have tried the http://www.bing.com/siteowner to use the code from there but When I search on my site it did not display anything,except that try this search on bing site etc. I want to know if I have to submit my site to bing before I have to use this search???

Comment: @junjua - As I said previously, perhaps you should try posting some code.  Tell us what you tried.  Where did you put the code on your site?  Which Getting Started option did you pick?  Where there any errors with what you tried?  If you only give us basic information then we can only give you basic answers ;)  A picture speaks a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to submit your site to Bing, but it might be a good idea if searches are not generating results. Bing has a web crawler, the so-called "BingBot" that indexes web content. It may have already found your site and indexed it. You might check the robots.txt file to make sure that it doesn't contain directives blocking crawlers.

To submit site to Bing:

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx

From personal experience - we didn't formally submit our site to Bing. We've got a Bing Box, and it's returning results.